# Describe generic dynamic behaviour using openAPI

Tags: openapi

Let's say I have an API that creates me a resource say `/create/my-resource/<resource-id>`. I want the consumers of the api to know that the response will always have an id field matching the one passed in the url, namely: `<resource-id>`.

I know I can use api examples to demonstrate this for a given id, say `2`. But is there a way of describing that generically, purely using open-api? The idea is to use the said behaviour when mocking.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI does not have syntax for that. You can only document such behavior in the `description` or using custom `x-` [extensions](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/).

Feel free to propose an enhancement for OpenAPI syntax here:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues